# Excel: How to create (static) array constant {1,2,3,...,100}

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to create a named array constant containing `{1,2,...,100}` in excel that is static and unchanging. I can do this manually for a short array like `{1,2,3,4,5}`, but I can't figure out a formulaic method.

I've tried to do this with the `ROW()` command by entering `=ROW(1:100)`, but this "constant" gets altered if I add or remove spreadsheet rows. For example, if I add a row between rows 2 and 3 the formula will become `=ROW(1:101)`.

The only method I've discovered is to use the `INDIRECT()` function,

```
=ROW(INDIRECT("A"&1):INDIRECT("A"&100))
```

but I can't imagine this is the recommended way to achieve this.

**[Edit]** A few more details to help clarify. I don't want to create this array anywhere on my spreadsheet. I just want to reference that range of numbers it in a formula.

My current desire to create such a named array constant is the following use case. Suppose I have a bunch of integers in column A and I want to determine the smallest in the range {200, 201, ... 300} that is *not* present in column A and put that value in cell B1. My method is

1. Create a named array constant say `'targetRange' =ROW(INDIRECT("A"&200):INDIRECT("A"&300))`
2. Place the following formula referencing the named array in B1: `=SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(A:A,targetRange)=0,targetRange,""),1)`.Create a named array constant say `'targetRange' =ROW(INDIRECT("A"&200):INDIRECT("A"&300))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `OFFSET` and `INDIRECT` are volatile. Since, in the following syntax, it is volatile "at workbook open only" (http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm), preferable is `INDEX`:

`ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,100))`

Note that the choice of column A (`A:A`) here is purely arbitrary.

Regards

Comment: And I would also suggest making this a Named Formula, especially if it needs to be used multiple times in a worksheet formula.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes, though I took that for granted from the OP's first line: 
I'd like to create a named array constant..."

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `=ROW(INDIRECT("200:300"))` is the usual way to do it.
The only other way I can think of, that might kind of work is something like

```
=Row(Offset(Index($A:$A,1),0,0,100,1))
```

Note that `{=ROW(1:100)}` results in a vertical array `{1;2;...;100}` and not a horizontal array `{1,2,...,100}`

Comment: Thanks! I rarely stretch the capabilities of Excel, so I figured I was just missing something. Thanks also for the vertical/horizontal clarification.

Comment: Looks like what I was missing is that you can use `INDIRECT` with a much simpler format. It appears that `ROW(INDIRECT("1:100"))` works in place of my `=ROW(INDIRECT("A"&1):INDIRECT("A"&100))`. This doesn't seem so convoluted. If you can confirm, could you edit your answer to clarify that there is an easier way to use `INDIRECT` than I was referencing.

Comment: Just a note that you can use TRANSPOSE to convert to a horizontal array if you needed it.

Comment: @RyanFeeley I was thinking of mentioning that it can be shortened to `INDIRECT("1:100")`, but I couldn't see the need for named range instead of just  `Row($200:$300)` in the example (maybe makes the formula easier to read), so I thought you might have a reason for writing it like that. Even `=INDIRECT("ROW(1:100)")` might work too.

Comment: What if you want an array of the same constant number: e.g. {5,5,5,5}.  How could you do that?

Comment: @user1527227 add `* 0 + 5` at the end

Answer (score 0):

To make it more succinct, the first INDEX can be dropped, as in

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,10)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use sequence?

`=SEQUENCE(,<total number>,[<starting number>])`

If I use `=SEQUENCE(,5)` in A1 and `=SEQUENCE(,5,3)` in A2, I get:

```
     A   B   C   D   E  
1  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
2  | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
```

The kicker here is that A1# and A2# become the reference to the entire array.  Or, I can use sequence() directly within another formula and it becomes an array of sequential values.